# Need clarification for NSAutoreleasePool

Tags: iphone, memory-management, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

Whenever we are calling `autorelease` method, its object is going to `NSAutoreleasePool`. When the pool is drained, it is sending release to all the objects in the pool.

**My question is;**
In the main function there is one `NSAutoreleasePool`. I want to know that; when we call the `autorelease` method, where it is sending the object ? I mean; it is sending the object to `NSAutoreleasePool` which is in main function **(or)** somewhere ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is actually a stack of autorelease pools. Whenever you do `[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]` that newly created pool is automatically put on top of the autorelease pool stack. You can create your own pools whenever you need it.

To be more precise: there is a stack of autorelease pools *on each thread*. So whenever you create a thread (for example with `[foo performSelectorInBackground:@selector(bar) withObject:baz]`) the very first thing you need to do is create a pool or else your objects leak (this creates the infamous messages like *"NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xd819d0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking"* and is a [very frequently asked question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599756/nsautorelease-memory-leak)).

When you call `autorelease`, the object is registered with the top-most autorelease pool of the current thread (that is: the one that was created last on that thread). The main run loop has its own autorelease pool that is emptied on each run loop iteration (AFAIK). The pool from `main.m` is there to catch any objects that for example might be generated internally by Cocoa Touch before it gets to create the run loop autorelease pool.

**Edit**: For more behind-the-scenes information, see [Mike Ash's *"Let's Build NSAutoreleasePool"*](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-02-lets-build-nsautoreleasepool.html)

Comment: +1 Nice explanation and refering to NSAutoreleaseNoPool() :-D

Comment: Update: Mike Ash wrote an excellent article on how one could implement NSAutoreleasePool yourself. See link in my edited answer.